# UITextView and UIPickerView with its own UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextview, uipickerview

I like to replicate the form behavior of Safari on the iPhone in my own app. If you enter data in an web form you get a separate UIToolbar (previous, next, done) just above the UIKeyboardView. Same for choosing an option: you get the same UIToolbar just above an UIPickerView.

I am looking for demos / sourcode / ideas how to implement this. Would I create my own subview with that toolbar and textview / pickerview? Is there a more elegant way? Especially something that leverages becomeFirstResponder of UITextfield?

Answer (score 13):

So i created a UIViewCOntroller subclass to manage this.

on that i wrote this function to add.

```
-(void) addToViewWithAnimation:(UIView *) theView
{
    UIView* myview = self.view;
    CGRect frame = myview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 420;
    myview.frame = frame;

    UIView* bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420)];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    bgView.alpha = 0.6;
    backgroundView = bgView;
    [theView addSubview: bgView];  // this adds in the dark background

    [theView addSubview:self.view]; // this adds in the pickerView with toolbar.
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  
    frame = myview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 420 - frame.size.height;
    myview.frame = frame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

I then created the view in IB, here is what my class Header looked like at the end of that. (there is also a UItoolbar on the view i just do not have a reference to it in my Controller)

```
@interface PropertyPickerController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIPickerView* Picker;
    IBOutlet UIButton* DoneButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton* CancelButton;
    UIView* backgroundView;
    NSArray* SimpleObjects;
    id PickerObjectDelegate;
    SEL PickerObjectSelector;
}
```

To then hide the view i use.

```
-(void) removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation
{

    UIView* myview = self.view;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(AnimationDidStop:)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  
    // set fram below window.   
    CGRect frame = myview.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 420;
    myview.frame = frame;
    backgroundView.alpha = 0;  //fades shade to nothing
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) AnimationDidStop:(id) object
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];  //removes view after animations.
    [backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

And last but not least all the delegate functions for the picker.

```
    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        FBSimpleObject* object = (FBSimpleObject*)[SimpleObjects objectAtIndex:row];
        return object.Name;
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {   
    }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    { return 1;}

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return [SimpleObjects count];
    }

    - (IBAction)CancelButtonClick
    {
            [self removeFromSuperviewWithAnimation];
    }
    - (IBAction)DoneButtonClick
    {   
//This performs a selector when the done button is clicked, makes the controller more versatile.
if(PickerObjectDelegate && PickerObjectSelector)
        {
            NSMethodSignature* signature = [PickerObjectDelegate methodSignatureForSelector:PickerObjectSelector];  
            NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
            [invocation setTarget:PickerObjectDelegate];
            [invocation setSelector:PickerObjectSelector];
            [invocation setArgument:&object atIndex:2];
            [invocation retainArguments];
            [invocation invoke];
        }
    }
```

This is how you do the ToolBar.  Basically i use the same concept with a ViewController subclass, and i dont use the standard push view or modal display options. (the example here actually places a Textbox and a toolbar on top of the keyboard.

@interface BugEditCommentController : UIViewController {
    UITextView* Comment;
    UIToolbar* Toolbar;
}
-(void) addToViewWithAnimation:(UIView*) theView;

To activate this view usually you would call [object becomeFirstResponder];
so if you add this to your view Controller constructor, all you need to do is call [object becomeFirstResponder];

```
 NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
     [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
     [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

abd if you implement this method on your controller (defined in the above code)

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) note
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    CGRect toolbarFrame  = Toolbar.frame;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    CGPoint keyboardCenter;
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardCenter];
    [[note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] getValue: &keyboardFrame];

    //CGRect toolbarRect = Toolbar.center;
    toolbarFrame.origin.y= keyboardCenter.y - ((keyboardFrame.size.height/2) + (toolbarFrame.size.height));
    Toolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(id) object
{

//you could call [self removeFromSuperviewHere];
}

-(void) removeFromsuperViewWithAnimation
{
    [Comment resignFirstResponder];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(AnimationDidStop:)];

    CGRect frame = Toolbar.frame;
    frame.origin.y = 480;
    Toolbar.frame = frame;

    [self.view viewWithTag:1].alpha = 0;  //fade transparent black background to clear.
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
-(void)AnimationDidStop:(id) object
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

hope the additional info helps.

Comment: Thanks. But the UITextView is missing. I'm not sure how to integrate that with the 'firstResponder' mechanism.

Comment: Sorry yes, that example is just the UIPickerView.
I'll post the code for the UITextView when i get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the solution for this issue too.

I found this was the best solution, you can use this SCKit to add tool bar to dismiss the UIPickerView or the UIDatePicker as you want.

Following is github link: https://github.com/scelis/SCKit/tree/

Have fun!