# how to show pickerview in uitextfield not the keyboard?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield, uipickerview

I want to show a UIPickerView on becoming FirstResponder of a UITextfield not the keyboard and fill the value in text field form the picker view.

any one knows this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit:** this answer was correct at the time of writing. Apple has since introduced `inputView`. Mafonya [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249439/1555903) is what you should be doing nowadays.

It is possible to prevent the keyboard from popping up. Set your class to be the delegate of the UITextField: `textField.delegate = self` and add: `<UITextFieldDelegate>` after your interface declaration (before the {) in the header file.

Now implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Show UIPickerView

    return NO;
}
```

If you want to be able to hide your pickerView this method won't work. What you could do then is create subclass of UITextField and override the `*trackingWithTouch:event:` selectors and do your magic in those. You probably still need to return NO from `textFieldShouldBeginEditting:` to prevent the keyboard from showing.

Comment: your solution works partially.i want to show picker view on some specific uitextfields not on all text fields and also when the value is selected from the picker view filled in the desired text field the picker view must be hidden.

Answer (score 28):

Use [textfield setInputView:pickerView];

Replacing the System Input Views
 
[inputView

  inputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Comment: This the correct answer for those who know what they are doing.

Comment: do you guys know the swift implementation of this ?

Answer (score 4):

Hey I have pasted in some code I wrote a while back to cover this scenario. There are two examples one with an actionsheet and one without an actionsheet:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)myTextField{

             [myTextField resignFirstResponder];

             actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

             [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

             CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

             UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

              pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

              pickerView.dataSource = self;

              pickerView.delegate = self;

              [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];

              [pickerView release]; //NB this may result on the pickerview going black the next time you come back to the textfield, if this is the case just remove this statement

              UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSLocalizedString(@"SUBMIT", @"")]];

              closeButton.momentary = YES;

               closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);

               closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

               closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

               [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

               [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

               [closeButton release];

               [actionSheet showInView:displayedInView];

               [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];

}
```

This is the code without the actionsheet:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)myTextField{

         [myTextField resignFirstResponder];

          for (int component = 0;  component &lt; (((NSInteger)numberOfComponentsForPickerView) - 1); component++) {

              NSInteger valueForRow = [[self.textField.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(component,1)] integerValue];

               [pickerView selectRow:valueForRow inComponent:component animated:YES];

          }

           [self fadeInPickerView];

            [view addSubview:pickerView];

            [pickerView release];

}
```

An more detailed example of this can be found at: http://www.buggyprogrammer.co.uk/2010/08/18/open-uipickerview-when-user-enters-textfield/

Answer (score 4):

add inputview to textField.

```
picker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
[picker setDataSource:self];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];

MyTextField.inputView = picker;
```

Comment: thanks! it works for me but how to hide the picker when we have make a choice? Thanks a lot

Comment: Worked For me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code at (there is both textview+tabbar and pickerview+tabbar code)

[UITextView and UIPickerView with its own UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885002/uitextview-and-uipickerview-with-its-own-uitoolbar/885342#885342)

this will get the pickerview to resign etc.  All u need to do then is use the pickerview delegate method to update the text view

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Instead of using a textfield, use a UIlabel, with a white background.  That way the keyboard will not show when you tap it. override the touches event on the UILabel, when that happens call the method form the privious question that will display the new view.

```
 -(void) addToViewWithAnimation:(UIView *) theView
```

Comment: i do not want the keyboard to show up only picker view is i want to be displayed when i enters in text field

Comment: yeah the keyboard will pretty much always show up. you will have to use another view such as uiLabel. i've edited the answer to be more concise.

Comment: As Blue mentioned, the keyboard will always show up and you can't avoid it. Another alternative would be to add a picker view on top of the keyboard. They are the same height, so the keyboard won't be seen.