# UIPickerView and UITextFields problems

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have multiple textFields. In one of them, i want to display a UIPickerView. 
I did it this way:

```
-(void)showPicker{
    [subject becomeFirstResponder];
    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0);

    picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    picker.dataSource = self;
    picker.delegate = self;

    [actionSheet addSubview:picker];
    [picker release];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];

    [actionSheet showInView:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];

    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];



}

-(void)dismissActionSheet{
    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

When i close it, the sheet is being dismissed, but the keyboard on the `subject` textField appears.

Now:

How can i do to not to show the keyboard on that `subject` textField?

Here is where i resign the keyboard:

```
- (void) resignKeyboard:(id)sender{

        if ([name isFirstResponder])
            [name resignFirstResponder];
        else if ([email isFirstResponder])
            [email resignFirstResponder];
        else if ([message isFirstResponder])
            [message resignFirstResponder];
        else if ([subject isFirstResponder]) {
            [subject resignFirstResponder];
        }

}
```

Comment: does this happen only to "subject" textField?

Comment: The subject field is the one that contains the UIPickerView. When i close it, the keyboard appears and it should not

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906112/how-to-show-pickerview-in-uitextfield-not-the-keyboard

Comment: A handy subclass to do this: https://github.com/CullenSUN/PickerTextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using a transparent button which handles the action to show the picker. The "subject" textField was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prevent the keyboard from popping up.

Firstly set your class as the delegate of UITexfield

```
 textField.delegate = self
```

In your Interface Declaration  add:

```
<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Now implement textFieldShouldBeginEditing::

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Show UIPickerView

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I am actually showing the UIPickerView with the means of a selector:     `[subject addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];`

Answer (score 0):

Use UItextField delegates: For that u need add @interface YourViewController  :UIViewController

If UItextField taken from xib by right clicking add its delegate to fileowner

Now use this method in code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   if(textField == subject)
   {
     return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: I was already using UITextField delegates, but it doesn't work anyways :\

Comment: add this method and tell how its going

Comment: Nothing happens, the keyboard keeps appearing

Comment: check this method is called by debugging if not read my answer again

Comment: I think that it's not called because i'm using a selector (so we can say that the textField "subject" acts like a button)