# how to set setInputAccessoryView for pickerview in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In iPhone App as we are displaying Toolbar with textField by:

```
[textField setInputAccessoryView:myToolBar]
```

can we do the same thing with pickerView?

if i use

```
[myPickerView setInputAccessoryView:myToolBar]
```

It is giving warning "pickerview may not respond to setinputAccessoryview"
what should I do ?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there is no such `setInputAccessoryView`  function in `UIPickerView`. class
If you are looking for using UIToolbar with UIPickerView See below ..

[UITextView and UIPickerView with its own UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885002/uitextview-and-uipickerview-with-its-own-uitoolbar)